# How to mock axios request in ES5 file?

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, axios

I have a project which makes multiple jquery ajax requests and Axios requests. I am mocking the response in a file outside the project. I am able to mock jquery requests using mockjx but unable to mock Axios requests.
The Axios request is made from React/Reducer's actions which are transpile to ES5. I don't have access to the XHR/Axios object to tweak it, outside the project.
Could anybody please guide on how do I mock Axios request from outside the React application in ES5 format?

Comment: you can use to mock  https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios-mock-adapter

Comment: It uses require method, i wont be able to use it in ES5, my ajax request is fired from react but i have to mock in native JS
var axios = require('axios');
var MockAdapter = require('axios-mock-adapter');